# UInt8/NSString with CFWriteStreamWrite

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Trying to create an app that does some socket communication (Writing only).

I can get it to work with a static value:

```
UInt8 buf[] = "play";
int bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, buf, strlen((char*)buf));
```

I'm a relative neophyte to C/Objective-C and I'm trying to figure out how to pass an NSString to a function and get the value into "buf".

```
-(void) sendData: (NSString *) command {
    UInt8 buf[] = ????;
    int bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, buf, strlen((char*)buf));
}
```

Obviously more to it than that...just isolating the relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the bytes behind an NSString using the `UTF8String` method.

```
CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream,
                   (const UInt8 *)[command UTF8String],
                   [command lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```